# How to modify CSS variable in an angular animation state

Tags: css, angular, animation

I'm creating a "draggable" component which can be moved on the page and plays an animation when destroyed. I am curently setting the `style.transform` attribute of the component host to `translate3d` to change its position on the document:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-window',
    templateUrl: './window.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./window.component.scss'],
    animations: [
        trigger('WindowAnimation', [
            state('void', style({ 
                opacity: '0',
                transform: 'scale(0)', // host is `display: block`
            })),
            transition('* => void', [
                animate('1000ms ease-out')
            ])
        ])
    ]
})
export class WindowComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input('left') public left: number = 0;
    @Input('top') public top: number = 0;
    @HostBinding('@WindowAnimation') animation: boolean = true;
    @HostBinding('style.transform') get hostTransform(): string {
        return `translate3d(${this.left}px, ${this.top}px, 0px)`;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `scale` part of the animation isn't played. I think this is because the component host already has a `style.transform` attribute given by the hostbinding: if I remove the `style.transform` hostbinding, the animation plays correctly, but I loose control over the component position. I then tried to solve the problem using CSS variable by replacing the hostbinding with the following:

```
@HostBinding('style.transform') get hostTransform(): string {
    return `translate3d(${this.left}px, ${this.top}px, 0px) scale(var(--host-scale, 1))`;
}
```

But then, I need to modify the `--host-scale` CSS variable during the animation. I tried something like this without any success:

```
// [...]
state('void', style({ 
    opacity: '0',
    '--host-scale': `0`, // fails at runtime with '"--host-scale" is not a supported CSS property for animations'
})),
// [...]
```

Is it possible to tell Angular to "add" a parameter to the already existing `style.transform` attribute or to change the value of a CSS variable during an animation ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but maybe its worth a try

I haven't worked with this myself but I can imagine you have to change how you trigger this whole thing. What I have done, is to attach the animation to a css-class and then toggle that on the component.

css:

```
.highlight {
    animation-name: highlightComponent;
    animation-duration: 5s;
}

@keyframes highlightComponent {
    from {
        background-color: rgba(14, 231, 255, 0.7);
    }
    to {
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    }
}
```

ts:

```
  highlightChanges(elementId: string) {
      document.getElementById(elementId).classList.add('highlight')
  }
```

Comment: my animation doesnt do the same as yours but maybe it can serve as inspiration

Comment: I just tried it (by adding the `::ng-deep` attribute to the css block and adding the class manually to the component host) and it doesn't seem to work: if I animate the `transform` property then the `translate3d` attribute is overriden and no longer applied. And if I instead animate the `--host-scale` CSS variable, the animation seems to work but is not interpolated: it only shows the two distinct states scale(1) and scale(1). Also, I don't think I can easily play the animaton when destroying the component (as with the `* => void` transition in the angular animations).

Comment: This is tuff, maybe this article can help you. 
https://angular.io/guide/animations#triggering-the-animation